# Need help seeing if a string contains a list of characters in order using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

My teacher gave me an assignment where there are two strings, a full word, and a substring that contains letters that might be in the full word. The objective is to use recursion to see if the full word contains the letters of the substring in order they are given. here are some examples of what I am talking about:

-"xd", "test" returns false because one or more of the substring letters does not exist in the full word.

-"ts", "test" returns true because both letters are found found in the full word.

-"trl", "turtle" returns true because all the letters are found in the full word and are found in the correct order.

-"tlr", "turtle" returns false because although the all the letters exist in the full word, they were not found in the substring's order.

I have tried:

```
public boolean contains_recursive(String partial, String full) {

    String[] partialArray = partial.split("");

    if(full.contains(partialArray[0])) {
        partialArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(partialArray, 1, partialArray.length);
        String newPartial = "";
        for(String character : partialArray) {
            System.out.println(character);
            newPartial += character;
        }
        contains_recursive(newPartial, full);
    }

    return false;
}
```

but do not know where to go from there. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
public boolean containsRecursive(String partial, String full) {
  if (partial.isEmpty()) return true;
  if (full.isEmpty()) return false;

  int firstOccurrence = full.indexOf(partial.charAt(0));

  return firstOccurrence >= 0 && containsRecursive(partial.substring(1), full.substring(firstOccurrence + 1));
}
```

**Explanation:**

```java
if (partial.isEmpty()) return true;
```

- If there is nothing to look for in the full string, then the "substring" technically exists (i.e. an empty string is a substring of all strings).

```java
if (full.isEmpty()) return false;
```

- If we've got to this point that means there are characters in the partial string that we're looking for but unfortunately the `full` string doesn't have any characters to compare to, so those characters in the `partial` string will definitely not be in `full`, return `false`.

```java
int firstOccurrence = full.indexOf(partial.charAt(0));
```

- We've got this far so both `partial` and `full` are non-empty, let's utilize [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)'s [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) instance method. This method will return the location of the first occurrence of the given character *or* `-1` if the character doesn't exist in the string.
- We use `partial.charAt(0)` because if the first character of `partial` doesn't exist in `full` then why should we check the remaining characters in `partial`? In other words, let's make sure that the first character exists before checking the rest.

```java
return firstOccurrence >= 0 && containsRecursive(partial.substring(1), full.substring(firstOccurrence + 1));
```

- We check `firstOccurrence >= 0` because if `firstOccurrence` is `-1` then that means `partial`'s first character wasn't in `full` so this should return `false`.
- The `&&` is used for short-circuiting. In other words, if `firstOccurrence >= 0` is `false` the second half of the boolean check (i.e. the recursive call) won't be evaluated because `false && anyOtherBooleanExpression ==> false`.
- The second half of boolean check is the recursive call. We only get this far if the first character of `partial` is in `full`. Now we call our function again by taking all the characters of `partial` **minus** its first character *or* `partial.substring(1)`.
- Since `firstOccurrence` represents the first location of the first character of `partial` in `full`, we don't care about the (possible) skipped locations.

  - For example, if `partial = "mtr"` and `full = "computer"`, `m` matches at position `2`, we should start checking `partial = "tr"` within `full = "puter"` on the next recursive call.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but does this check to make sure that the characters from the partial are found in the same order as they were found in the full?

Comment: Yes, look at the "For example" bit at the end of the post. The `substring` calls handle the order. Try `containsRecursive("se", "test")`, it should return `false`. Because although `"se"` contains characters that are in `"test"`, `'s'` comes after `'e'` in the full string, so this is correct.